# bootstrapping rails collection_select and date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

On my rails app, i have a collection_select and date_select on the form, but can't find any info on how to add the bootstrap class to customize the fields.

```
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= form.label :exercise_id %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:exercise_id, Exercise.all, :id, :name, prompt: true, {}, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
</div>

<div class="field form-group">
  <%= form.label "Date" %>
  <%= form.date_select :activitydate, {}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
</div>
```

I get an error because of the collection_select syntax.
The date_select syntax works but I want to customize the individual  tags generated..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tiago, could you please put in the specific code you are trying to work on, so that you are able to get good quality answers?

Comment: question edited adding the code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is sample code for bootstrap 4 with rails, if you using bootstrap 3, just change col-form-label with form-label

usually collection_select is use for multiple selections, this is the reason using **array exercise_ids** and **multiple: true** like this below

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <%= form.label "Choose Exercises", :class => 'col-form-label col-sm-4' %>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <%= form.collection_select :exercise_ids, Exercise.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true, class: 'form-control' } %>
  </div>  
</div>
```

if you plan to choose one exercise then (personal suggestion) use select

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <%= form.label "Choose Exercises", :class => 'col-form-label col-sm-4' %>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <%= f.select :exercise_id, Exercise.all, { include_blank: true } , { class:  'form-control' }  %>
  </div>  
</div>
```

for date helper you can [check here for reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) so you can customize it